# ABPersonViewController and hiding the Cancel Button

Tags: iphone

ABPersonViewController is by default showing a "Cancel" button in the right button bar position.  How would one go about hiding/clearing that item?  Obligatory code sample follows:

```
ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
picker.personViewDelegate = self;
picker.displayedPerson = aPerson;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
```

Thanks.

Comment: SOLVED!  Subclass ABPersonViewController, override -(void) viewDidLoad, call the super and THEN set the rightBarButtonItem to nil.  Ta da!

@interface PersonViewController : ABPersonViewController

@end


@implementation PersonViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
@end

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED! Subclass `ABPersonViewController`, override `-(void) viewDidLoad`, call the super and THEN set the `rightBarButtonItem` to `nil`. Ta da!

```
@interface PersonViewController : ABPersonViewController
@end

@implementation PersonViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Be sure to mark your own answer as accepted so it's easy for others to refer to your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler:

```
ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
picker.personViewDelegate = self;
picker.displayedPerson = aPerson;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
picker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil; // remove "Cancel" button
[picker release];
```

(Simply added rightBarButtonItem = nil after pushViewController.)

Comment: Seems to be a regression in iOS 4. My code works pre-iOS4, where I could add the rightBarButtonItem before hand, now I have to add it AFTER I call presentModalViewController on the UINavigationController that contains my ABPersonViewController.